# Are XML parsers safe from XML External Entity (XML) injection in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, security, .net-core, xxe

I am trying to determine if a .NET Core application is vulnerable to XML External Entity (XXE) injection attacks. I read [this OWASP XXE Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) which tells me, for example, that `XmlDocument` is unsafe by default in .NET Framework versions prior to 4.5.2. I cannot find any similar documentation for .NET Core versions. I see that .NET Core was released within a few months of .NET Framework 4.6.2. Can I therefore assume that these XML parsers are safe by default in .NET Core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML parsers I tested have the same characteristics in .NET Core 2.1 as they do in .NET Framework 4.5.2 (at least with respect to XXE injection). To respond to the specific example I gave in the question, `XmlDocument` is unsafe by default in .NET Framework 4.5.1, but safe by default in both .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .NET Core 2.1.

In order to convince myself of this fact, I performed testing for .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2, and .NET Core 2.1. My code and results are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/samuel-knutson/dotnet-xxe-learning-tests).